# Error uploading files CKAN

Tags: solr, jetty, ckan

I am trying to upload data to CKAN, and I can do that for smaller files (I have uploaded 4 kB successfully), however for bigger files (with a file of 18 MB I already got this error), I get `Error 500 An internal server error occurred`.
In the command prompt where I am running CKAN I get

```
Error - <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>: [Error 32] The file is already being used by another process: u'C:\\src\\ckan\\ckan\\resources\\a3d\\19a\\ba-7f3f-42fc-
a02e-09f50aae0924~'
URL: http://localhost:5000/dataset/new_resource/test1
```

I don't know what that file is, but I am pretty sure this error is the reason why I can't upload larger files, as it is the only error I get.

Important to say that I can successfully add resources from URL and from small files, but when trying with larger files, I get this error.

Does anyone have any idea on what could be wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain that Windows-Error, but generally CKAN has an upload size limit of 10MB for resources by default. You can raise that in your ini with `ckan.max_resource_size = XX`, for example `ckan.max_resource_size = 100` (which means = 100MB).

Comment: Increasing that limit solved the problem and I dont get this Windows-Error anymore. Thank you very much.